# Regex (search/replace/add) VIM

Tags: regex, search, vim

I am trying to search and replace in my file.

example:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "blog.post", "fields": {"text": "asdadasdasd", "genre": 8, 
"image": "image/test.jpg", "created_at": "2013-04-09T19:22:45Z", 
"updated_at": "2013-04-09T19:22:45Z", "help": 12, "reference": 12, 
"title": "Test1", "slug": "test-1"}}]
```

Iam need search: "genre": 8 and replace or add: "genre": [8]

```
Use:
:g/"genre": \d/s//[&]/g
```

But problem: ["genre": 8] Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
:%s/\("genre": \)\(\d\d*\)/\1[\2]/g
```

This uses capturing groups, the `\1` in the replacement refers to the group `\("genre": \)`, and the `\2` in the replacement refers to the `\(\d\d*\)`.  Note that I changed this from just `\d` to `\d\d*` so that it will match multiple digit numbers as well, otherwise something like `"genre": 80` would get replaced by `"genre": [8]0`.

Comment: Hello @F.J thanks work 100% ;) 1+

Answer (score 2):

this line should solve your problem:

```
:%s/"genre": \zs\d\+\ze/[&]/g
```

`\zs and \ze` make the substitution only match the numbers following `"genre":(one space)`. so that in replacement could simply use `&`.

```
:h \zs
:h \ze
```

for detail

Comment: Yes, I understand a little more about it. Thanks for your help. Sorry I can not give reputation.

Comment: @SoyLatam you don't need to give any reputation. if an answer is helpful to you, you could click the up arrow (above the "0") to upvote. or accept it by clicking the tick as correct answer if it solved your problem.